# Android Studio: Accidentally ignored "xmlns" attribute

Tags: android-studio

Using Android Studio in the XML-Layout-editor,

When an error saying something about the xmlns not being found, I checked quickly for a fix with the help of the editor, and I chose one that said something about ignore.

Suddenly, this error,

```
    <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ....

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Where it says `element RelativeLayout must be declared` and this follows for all childrens aswell.
The `<RelativeLayout` is the part that has the error. Also the childern, such as `<LinearLayout` has this error.

Where can I remove the ignore?

Answer (score 0):

> You can check if the file is in "layout" folder.

I also met the error `element RelativeLayout must be declared`. I realized that my file was located in "drawable" folder, instead of the "layout" folder. That's why the error showed up.